# Can't connect to the device with ADB when it's in recovery mode

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, shell

I am having some problems with my Samsung Galaxy S2 and I want to start an `fschk` session on the device.

So, I installed Android SDK with platform-tools. I can access to the device when it's normally rebooted but I couldn't list and connect to the device when it's in recovery mode.

How can I connect via ADB when the device is in recovery mode?

Comment: What OS are you running on? It sounds like the recovery is a stock recovery and therefore un-rooted hence lack of access to adb shell from there.

Comment: I rooted the device about a year ago by following a how-to and didn't update it since then. It runs Android 2.2.3 GINGERBREAD.XWKG1.

Comment: I meant, are you running Windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm not certain that this is possible. I seem to remember that when I was rooting my N7 I was unable to adb while in recovery. I believe you have to be either fully booted or with just the bootloader... booted.

Comment: As I read, it's possible.

I am on Windows and I installed the Google's USB drivers. I am trying to install a custom recovery but my phone is acting quite strange. I think I'll try the same steps on Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**WARNING: fastboot oem unlock completely wipes your data!**

adb is not available in the bootloader, try using fastboot instead

for a quick and dirty rundown of flashing your device with a new image using fastboot:

`adb reboot bootloader`
use `fastboot devices` to verify your device is visible, if not, you're probably running windows, and you have to install some funky drivers.
if you don't see 'unlocked' at the bottom of the screen, use the command `fastboot oem unlock`
then just:
`fastboot flash boot boot.img`
`fastboot flash system system.img`
`fastboot flash userdata userdata.img`
`fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`

If you feel super confident you could just:
`adb reboot bootloader && fastboot oem unlock && fastboot flash boot boot.img && fastboot flash system system.img && fastboot flash userdata userdata.img && fastboot flash recovery recovery.img && fastboot reboot`

PS You should only use the flash commands if the referenced files are present, if not you may or may not brick your phone (haven't tried flashing a non-existent file to the device yet)

**Warning: Unlocking bootloader wipes off data in your phone.**

Comment: How we can run these commands when device does not recognized!
error: device not found

Comment: If you're using Winows, install Linux.If you're using Linux - I've never had an issue with bootloader connectivity, so can't help you there. However, if you're talking about for the `adb reboot bootloader` line, each device is a little different about how to get adb to recognize the device. I suggest you look it up for your particular device.

Comment: Holy crap, couldn't you have added a warning that `fastboot oem unlock` *completely wipes your data*?

Answer (score 5):

Stock recovery doesn't come with ADB access.

Try a recent version of [ClockworkMod recovery](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager) for your device (the older versions don't all have ADB support)

You will need to flash the recovery on using fastboot (see @MishaP's answer)